# If a set is finite, there is a bijection from the set to $\{1,\cdots,n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
$
**Definitions**:
A set $X$ is finite iff there is an injection, but no bijection, from $X$ to $\N$.
$I_n = \{i \in \N~|~i \le n\}$

**Claim**:
If $X$ is finite, there is a bijection from $I_n$ to $X$ for some $n \in \N$.

The finiteness of a set is usually defined by the existence of the bijection to $I_n$, but I want to show it from the other definition that is more abstract. I think I have to actually construct the bijection in question, but I don't even know how to find $n$.

Comment: Since $X$ is finite, there exist an injection from $X$ into $\mathbb{N}$. Consider the range $f(X)$, which is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ in bijection with $X$

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma:** *If $X$ is finite and $\iota\colon X\longrightarrow\Bbb N$ is an injection, then $\iota(X)$ has an upper bound.*

**Proof:** Suppose otherwise. That is, suppose that $X$ is finite and that there is an injection $\iota\colon X\longrightarrow\Bbb N$ such that $\iota(X)$ has no upper bound. In particular, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is some $x_n\in X$ such that $\iota(x_n)>n$. So, it makes sense to define $f\colon\Bbb N\longrightarrow X$ as follows: $f(1)$ is the element of $X$ such that $\iota\bigl(f(1)\bigr)$ is the smallest element of $\iota(X)$ and, if $f(n)$ is already defined, $f(n+1)$ is the element of $X$ such that$$\iota\bigl(f(n+1)\bigr)=\text{smallest element of }\Bbb N\setminus\bigl\{f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(n)\bigr\};$$note that $\Bbb N\setminus\bigl\{f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(n)\bigr\}$ is not empty, since, if $N=\max\bigl\{f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(n)\bigr\}$, $\iota(x_N)$ is bigger than any element of $\bigl\{f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(n)\bigr\}$. It is clear that $f$ is an injection and therefore, since there is an injection from $X$ into $\Bbb N$ and there is an injection from $\Bbb N$ into $X$, there is a bijection between them, by the Schröder–Bernstein theorem. But we are assuming that no such bijection exists.

---

So, for each injection $\iota\colon X\longrightarrow\Bbb N$ there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $(\forall x\in X):\iota(x)\leqslant m$. And now it is easy to prove by induction on $m$ that there is a bijection from $X$ onto $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I've been struggling to understand your answer, but I am confused now. The definition of $f$ doesn't seem to make sense to me because the codomain of $f$ is $X$, but you are taking set difference of $\mathbb{N}$ w.r.t. the image of $f$. How is it justified? I realized that it suffice to find an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ into $X$ to prove the claim, and your answer can be a direct answer to it.