# If the image of an injection from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded, $X$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
$
**Claim**:
Let $X$ be a set. Suppose that there is an injection $f$ from $X$ to $\N$, and its range $f[X]$ has an upper bound. Then, there is $n \in \N$ such that there is a bijection $h$ from  $I_n = \{i \in \N~|~ i \le n\}$ onto $f[X]$.

This seems obvious but I failed to find such $n$. Is there a constructive way to find $n$? If not, how can I ensure the existence of $n$?

This is a continued question about the answer by [Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4352535/334795).

Comment: There is basically only one way to ever prove anything about the natural numbers: induction.

Answer (score -1):

Let $n_{0} \in \Bbb N$ an upper bound of $ f[ X ]$ then $\{1,2,3 ,\cdots, n_{0} \} $ is a co-domain of $f.$  Also let $n_{1}$ denote the Cardinality of $X$, since $f$ is one-one, $n_{1}$ is also the Cardinality  of  $ f[ X ].$

Since we the set of images must be a subset of codomain, we have
$$n_{1} \leq n_{0}$$

Use this $n_{1}$  for your $I_{n}.$